# Jenkins hangs the browser when downloading build artifacts

Tags: firefox, jenkins

It seems like whenever I go and download a build artifact, the browser ends up hanging for a couple of minutes and seems to resume once the download actually starts. I'm currently using Firefox 17.0.8. Currently we're using Jenkins version 1.457.

Comment: There is no Jenkins version `1.4.7`... Jenkins version numbers are things like `1.470`, `1.530`, etc. because there have been over 500 releases of Jenkins. The three segment version numbers are for the LTS stable line and there are only a few of them: `1.509.x`, `1.480.x`, `1.466.x`, `1.447.x`, etc. As a Jenkins developer I can state with 100% confidence that you have written down the wrong version number

Comment: Good catch, I copied pasted it wrong and have updated the question.

Comment: This may actually be caused by the corporate virus scanner when I download a big file. (Not sure what the threshold for big is).